# Pandas: take the minimum of two operations on two dataframes, while preserving index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I'm a beginner with Pandas. I've got two dataframes df1 and df2 of three columns each, labelled by some index.

I would like to get a third dataframe whose entries are
min( df1-df2, 1-df1-df2 )
for each column, while preserving the index.

I don't know how to do this on all the three columns at once. If I try e.g. `np.min( df1-df2, 1-df1-df2 )` I get `TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`, whereas `min( df1-df2, 1-df1+df2 )` gives `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I can't use `apply` because I've got more than one dataframe. Basically, I would like to use something like `subtract`, but with the ability to define my own function.

Example: consider these two dataframes
`df0 = pd.DataFrame( [[0.1,0.2,0.3], [0.3, 0.1, 0.2], [0.1, 0.3, 0.9]], index=[2,1,3], columns=['px', 'py', 'pz'] )`

```
In [4]: df0
Out[4]: 
    px   py   pz
2  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  0.3  0.1  0.2
3  0.1  0.3  0.9
```

and

`df1 = pd.DataFrame( [[0.9,0.1,0.9], [0.1,0.2,0.1], [0.3,0.1,0.8]], index=[3,1,2], columns=['px', 'py', 'pz'])`

```
    px   py   pz
3  0.9  0.1  0.9
1  0.1  0.2  0.1
2  0.3  0.1  0.8
```

my desired output is a new dataframe df, made up of three columns 'px', 'py', 'pz', whose entries are:

```
   for j in range(1,4):
       dfx[j-1] = min( df0['px'][j] - df1['px'][j], 1 - df0['px'][j] + df1['px'][j] )
```

for df['px'], and similarly for 'py' and 'pz'.

```
    px   py   pz
1  0.2 -0.1  0.1
2 -0.2  0.1 -0.5
3 -0.8  0.2  0.0
```

I hope it's clear now! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for this question. It's almost impossible to create an answer without knowing your actual inputs and desired output.

Comment: I hope it's ok now

Comment: @BeRT2me, for some reason I can't add this comment to your post below...
Unfortunately, that doesn't answer my question. I need df0-df1 only if that's the minimum between (df0-df1, 1-df0+df1). 
I'm aware this is not the way to use Pandas, otherwise there would be no need for Pandas! I'm expecting Pandas to be smart

Comment: I'd deleted my answer to make updates, since I realized you were asking a slightly different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` is smart enough to match up the columns and index values for you in a vectorized way. If you're looping a dataframe, you're probably doing it wrong.

```py
m1 = df0 - df1
m2 = 1 - (df0 + df1)

# Take the values from m1 where they're less than
# The corresponding value in m2. Otherwise, take m2:
out = m1[m1.lt(m2)].combine_first(m2)

# Another method: Combine our two calculated frames, 
# groupby the index, and take the minimum.
out = pd.concat([m1, m2]).groupby(level=0).min()
print(out)

# Output:

    px   py   pz
1  0.2 -0.1  0.1
2 -0.2  0.1 -0.5
3 -0.8  0.2 -0.8
```

Comment: Yup! It does it! Thanks a lot! This combine_first method is pretty cool